# How to write javascript for Yes No modalDialog Box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

how can we write javascript for sharepoint2010 confirmation ModalDialog popup with Yes NO buttons?

Thank you.

**I wrote like this.. but which is not working.. please anybody help.**

```
function OpenConfigurationDialog(ConfirmationMessage) 
{
  var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div');
  $("#lblConfirmationMessage").html(ConfirmationMessage);
  cloneModalContent.innerHTML = document.getElementById('ConfirmBox').innerHTML;

   var options = {
   html: cloneModalContent, // ID of the HTML tag or HTML content to be displayed in modal dialog
    width: 375,
   height: 150,
   title: "Please Confirm",
   dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialog, // custom callback function
   allowMaximize: false,
   showClose: true
};

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}


function CloseDialog(dialogResult, returnValue)
{

  if (returnValue == 'Yes') 
   {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
    alert('Hi 1');
    return true;
   }

  if (returnValue == 'No')
  {
   alert('Hi 2');
    return false;

  }
}
**And placed div tags in PlaceholderMain in sp Designer 2010 aspx page.**

    <div id="ConfirmBox" style="display:none;">
    <div id="messageDiv" style="height:100px; padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px; font-weight:bold;">
    <label id="lblConfirmationMessage"> </label>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonDiv" style="float:right;padding-right:5px;">
    <input type="button" style="width:75px;" value="Yes" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Yes, 'Yes'); return false;" />
    <input type="button" style="width:75px;" value="No" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel, 'No'); return false;"/>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnButtonClicked" value=""/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hello Robert.. can you give any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

If it just a popup to confirm something, just use javascripts inbuild `confirm();` function.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(confirm("Are you sure you are human?")) {
    alert("He is a human!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: No daniel it shows Ok Cancel buttons... need Yes No buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 provides the Modal Popup that can be customized to implement the Confirmation box. Please check this article: [Creating Custom Confirmation/Information Box in SharePoint 2010](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sharepoint-custom-modal-pop-up-confirmation-dialog-box).

Hope it will guide you to solution..

In your code in the question you have not closed the `function CloseDialog(dialogResult, returnValue)` tag properly. `}` is missing at the end.

Have you tried to debug the js using IE-->F12 ? Are you getting any error? Does the control go into the JS code? Where does it stop?

Comment: Already Ashish did give that link Nachiket.. the thing is i'm unable execute the above script... Thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug using IE->F12 ? Are you getting any error? Does the control go into the JS code?

Comment: yes Nachiket.. it is not showing any error . couldnt get output.

Comment: OK, answer the foll. questions:- 1. Do you know how to use debugger to debug the js? 2. Where does the debugger reach? 3. Are you using VS or Designer to deploy?

Comment: Nachiket.. Is it correct way to place div tags content in PlaceHolderMain in aspx page in sp designer. Any alternative way to place that div tags?

Comment: Thats OK, are you able to see the DIV contents when you load the page? Please ans. my questions 1,2 and 3.

Comment: I'm not using vs . debugging with IE10 now.

Comment: I wrote on Button click : onclick="javascript:OpenConfigurationDialog('Are you sure you want to delete this?')".

Comment: Are you able to see the DIV contents when you load the page?  Does the debugger reach javascript:OpenConfigurationDialog function when the button is clicked??

Comment: its not showing any errors and cursor stands at first line (function name)

Comment: Im using IE10 .. i think it has no such options to line by line checking..

Comment: on pressing F10, does it go inside the function on 1st line:- var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div');?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13604/discussion-between-praveen-ji-and-nachiket-kamat)

Comment: Please update all your recent finding in your question so others can get clear picture of your code and status.

Comment: this time showing error: SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

Comment: For rectifying $ error .. need to add jquery library?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <div id="ConfirmPopup" style="display:none;">
    <div id="messageDiv" style="height:100px; padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px; font-weight:bold;">
    <label id="lblConfirmationMessage"> /label>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonDiv" style="float:right;padding-right:5px;">
    <input type="button" style="width:75px;" value="Yes" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Yes, 'Yes'); return false;" />
    <input type="button" style="width:75px;" value="No" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel, 'No'); return false;"/>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnButtonClicked" value=""/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Source:[Click Here](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sharepoint-custom-modal-pop-up-confirmation-dialog-box)

Comment: You surely do not need jQuery for this..

Comment: Ya Robert.. Im also not looking for jquery.. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Is it possible with SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog() ?

Comment: Robert Your solution for this?

Comment: @pravin ..see my updated answer

Comment: Where do I have to place this script? Actually I wrote js in notepad. If I place above div's it is showing syntax errors. And how can I write the conditions like if 'Yes': something or 'No' : closing form.   Thanks Ashish

Comment: have you read the link which I provided?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13596/discussion-between-praveen-ji-and-ashish)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on how to do it using jQuery and the native Dialog framework.

http://sharepointbrandon.com/2012/08/confirmation-modal-dialog-using-sharepoint-2010-modaldialog-vs-jquery-ui-modal-dialog/

The code is also featured on the Technet gallery: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Confirmatio-06a8ebc5

Answer (score 0):

Is you case correct,  cancel is this with a capital C
      SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel